# Get selected option from backend using Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony

How can i init my select with option, that selects on backend (Symfony). Now i init my select (`ng-model="myselect"` example) like `ng-init="myselect='0'"`
I need to set actual selected option in `ng-init`, but if i remove `ng-init` directive it creates empty option with value `? undefined:undefined ?`
What should i do?

Comment: just set the model value in controller whatever u want to select by default

Comment: @gaurav I want to make a filter that memorize select value with page refresh. After form submittion select returning with right selected option, but angular overrides that. If i use ng-init = 0, selected option becomes option with value='0', if i remove ng-init it creates empty option already selected by default and override backend response.

Comment: If i remove all angular directives from select backend returns right selected option

Comment: I cannot set any attributes on options, they automatically generate on server

Comment: watch the select model value and save it to localsotrage, on page reload check if value exists and if it does set the value to model

Comment: @gaurav I thought about it, but i wanted better solution. For example backend sends me checked chekboxes and i can set it into angular model

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for but there's a `selected` property for all array values returned by the server. Works pretty much like the `ng-init` value. You can store that in a scope like `$scope.mySelect.selected = valueReturnedFromServer;`. In the view you can use `{{mySelect.selected}}` instead of `ng-init`.

Comment: @user371 You talking about ajax request for getting array of selected options? On our site everything is static without such thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to win this problem.

Anonymous function that turn vanilla html selects into angular models using my own function that converts string into object reference.

```
(function(){
    window.selectControl = [];
    var selects = document.querySelectorAll(".filter__select_range");
    selects.forEach( function(elem, index) {
      var _elem = angular.element(elem);

      if (elem.querySelector("[selected]") !== undefined) {
        window.selectControl[_elem.attr("data-model")] = elem.querySelector("[selected]").value;
        _elem.attr({
          "ng-model": _elem.attr("data-model"),
          "ng-change": _elem.attr("data-change"),
          "ng-init": _elem.attr("data-model") + "='"+ _elem.find('option:selected').val() +"'",
        });

        _elem.removeAttr('data-model').removeAttr('data-change');
        stringToPath($scope, _elem.attr('ng-model'), elem.querySelector("[selected]").value);
      }
    });
  })();
```

And `stringToPath` function

```
function stringToPath(obj, str, val) {
    str = str.split(".");

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      if (i != str.length-1 && str[i] != '') {
        if (typeof obj[str[i]] !== "object") {
          obj[str[i]] = {}
        }
        stringToPath(obj[str[i]], str.splice(1).join("."), val);
      }
      else {
        obj[str[i]] = val;
      }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

And one of my select in twig syntax

```
{{- form_widget(form, {'attr': attr|merge({'class': 'filter__select filter__select_range', 'data-model': 'FilterCollection.range.area.min', 'data-change': "checkSelectedFilters();"})}) -}}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
  <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
       <select 
        ng-options="p.id as  p.first + ' ' + p.last for p in people"
        ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>

    {{ selectedPerson }}
</fieldset>
```

```
 var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
 myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
 $scope.selectedPerson = 2;
 $scope.people = [
    { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo', actor: 'Silvester' },
    { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa', actor: 'Silvester' },
    { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble', actor: 'Arnold' },
    { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards', actor: 'Arnold' }
    ];
 });
```

This is what you expected..
Also check with this link http://jsfiddle.net/kaehejgo/

Comment: That is not exactly what i wanted. It's client object definition. I need to set select value from `url`.  
I see only two possible solutions:
1. Using localstorage
2. Using url exploding
I thought it was more elegant way to get default html value